# Two Api connection via docker-compose and docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

We have one API project with DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 43001
EXPOSE 43002

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Api.csproj Api/
RUN dotnet restore Api/Api.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet build Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet publish Api.csproj --no-restore --no-self-contained -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

And with `docker-compose`

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  Api:
    image: Api
    restart: always
    environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "43001:80"
      - "43002:443"
```

This project pushed to private docker registry.

And we have second Prod project that should use and connect to Api project.
`docker-compose` Prod project:

```
 version: '3.5'

services:
  Prod:
    image: Prod
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Prod/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - Api
    networks:
      - proxy-net
    expose:
      - "80"

  Api:
    image: {RegistryAddress}/Api
    restart: always
    networks:
      - proxy-net
    ports:
      - "43002:443"

networks:
  proxy-net:
    external:
      name: proxy-net
```

Issue - When I am connecting from Prod to Api I am getting Connection refused. Perhaps something with ports settings, but I tried a lot of changes and it didn`t help.  I thought Api ports settings should be enough, but looks like we need to set something in Prod also.

Comment: The first Compose file has a couple of `environment:` settings for the API container; do you need to repeat these in the second file?  (Nothing in the Compose setup beyond the built image and its name is considered or preserved when you push to a registry.)

Comment: Maybe i don't need the environmets in the first file if you say it doesn't push to the registry. But I don't think it will solve my problem. But I`ll try. Thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze no, same thing. Connection refused. I deleted almost all from file1 except image and build